New GCP IAM User Not Receiving Access or Email Notifications at Organization Lvl
I'm relatively new to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and encountered an issue while trying to add a new IAM user at the organization level. Specifically, I added a user as an Owner using their Gmail ID, but they aren't receiving any access or email notifications from GCP.
I’ve already come across a similar question on Stack Overflow: Stackoverflow Question. However, that question primarily addresses this issue at the project level. Unfortunately, I haven't found any solution or discussion specific to resolving this issue at the organization level.
Few Steps I've Taken:

Checked Spam Folders: I verified that no emails were delivered to the spam/junk folders.
Tested Other Roles: I also tried assigning the user the Organization Administrator role at the organization level, thinking it might be an access-related issue, but still, no email notifications were received.
Project-Level Testing: When I added the same user as an Owner at the project level, everything worked as expected. The user received the email notification immediately and gained access to the project.

Question:
Why isn’t the user receiving email notifications or gaining access when added as an Owner at the organization level, and how can I resolve this issue?

I couldn't find the documentation of this (at least not specifically for this case https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy) but AFAIK this is an expected behavior and not an issue. Imagine how many emails a user could get? A couple or hundreds depending on the organization or level you're granting the role

@Puteri So, what if I want to give a user access to a complete organization or multiple folders or projects. Do I need to go to every project and assign him the access separately? This don't seems to be the right way.

Nope, you assign it to the folder or organization. The thing is that that they won't receive the "invitation emai" in those cases and that's all, it doesn't mean they won't gain access as owner. So the issue you describe is that even with that they don't have access, can you add a screenshot of the error message the user got?
